# Why is .index faster than .all?

Tags: ruby, performance

Here are two simple blocks that do the same thing:

```
a = (0..100).to_a

a.all? do |x|
  !(x == 1000)
end

nil == a.index do |x|
  x == 1000
end
```

Except that the second one is consistently a little bit faster. Why?

```
                                     user     system      total        real
testing all                      1.140000   0.000000   1.140000 (  1.144535)
testing index                    0.770000   0.000000   0.770000 (  0.769195)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `index` is a method of `Array`. Ruby will iterate (in C) over the items and yield them to the block in turn.

On the other hand, `all?`, `none?`, `one?` (which will all be around 30% slower), are methods of `Enumerable`. They will call `each`, which will yield to a C function which will yield to the block. The difference in timing is due to the fact that there are two `yield`s involved.

Note that specialized versions of `all?` et al. could be defined on `Array` and you would get the same performance as `index`, but that would be a bit ugly and redundant...

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of the extra step `!` done in each turn of the iteration with `all?`.

Comment: Really? With that logic `x != 1000` should be as fast?

Comment: @LeeJarvis Provided that `!=` is defined in C in a similar algorithm as `==` is defined, that should be the prediction.

Comment: Changing it from `!(x == 1000)` to `x != 1000` does not make a significant difference.

Comment: @VladtheImpala How is `!=` implemented?

Comment: @VladtheImpala If you want to test this, what you should really compare is `a.none? do |x|
  x == 1000
end`